# Reputation change stats discrepancy

Tags: discussion, reputation

In my profile reputation change on Pets beta, It show -129

[image]

but In the user drop down it shows -24

[image]

What is the reason for this?

Comment: This is something, unfortunately, that normal users can't really answer, and will likely have to wait for moderators (of which we have none at the moment) or a Community Manager to investigate. (Just so you don't worry about why it might not get answered quickly.)

Comment: Your profile shows only -64 to me …

Comment: did you click "Show Removed Posts" in your reputation tab?

Answer (score 3):

99% of the time when your reputation change in the dropdown does not match what is shown in the reputation tab or there is another mismatch, the discrepancy is related to removed posts.

First make sure you click "Show Removed Posts" in your reputation tab.  That will show all changes in rep including ones from removed posts.

Generally speaking, reputation changes due to removed posts is officially counted on the day it was earned not the day the post was deleted (effectively making it like the reputation never existed) and I believe your user dropdown reflects this actual reputation, whereas your profile shows your reputation changes.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you received multiple upvotes beyond the reputation cap. If such an upvote is retracted, you wont lose any actual reputation, as none was given to you in the first place.

I guess that the profile shows your loss by votes and the dropdown shows the actual loss, which would explain the difference.

Comment: I lost 129 reputation so I don't think this is the reason